# Send e-mail including post meta when post is published

Tags: php, wordpress, email

i have a problem with sending e-mails from wordpress when a post is published. I am able to do this in the default way, but I need a little customization.

**Current Setup:** 
I have a custom post type with some metadata including an email address. Now I want to send an automated email to this address when the post is published. Here's the Code:

```
function post_published_notification( $post_id ) {
    $to = get_post_meta($post_id, "email_address", true);
    $subject = "some subject";
    $message = "some message";
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message);
}
add_action( 'publish_cpt', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

I tested it with a static email and its working. I also got the postmeta within another function.

Maybe the postmeta is not registered in the database at the time when this email is sent, but i am not really sure about this, because stuff like the title actually is.

Please help me with this and thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding `headers` in?

`$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );`

Comment: Yeah I tried it with adding headers but its still not working.